# Почему белый экран на backend?

Tags: yii2

Слетела система очень жестко слетела, восстановить файлы не удалось, поэтому сайт пришлось копировать с хоста. Но вот теперь при входе на backend белый экран причем `access.log` выдает

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2016:09:48:30 +0300] "GET /backend/web/ HTTP/1.1" 200 277 "http://cremea.lc/backend/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2016:09:57:34 +0300] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 278 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2016:09:56:09 +0300] "GET /backend/web/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 278 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
```

отображение ошибок включено

```
display_errors=on
display_startup_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Comment: помимо `access.log` есть еще `error.log`

Comment: ошибку нашел но вот вопрос возник если http 200 ok hfpdt error.log записываетс у меня не записывалось